# Laravel pagination not working with closure

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent, closures

I am trying to implement search functionality using Laravel. Here is my method that should return results of search:

```
$keyword = request('q');
$posts = Post::where('deleted', false)
                            ->where(function($q) use($keyword) {
                                        $q->where('title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                                        ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
                                    })     
                            ->latest()
                            ->paginate(5);
```

The problem is when I search for something that has more than 5 results it shows first 5 results and 2(for example) pages in links, but then when I click on the second page there are somehow 3 pages in links and some of the posts are repeated. I am guessing that closure is causing this problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Any advice is welcome, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using data from the request, you need to append it to be able to use in the next request:

```
{{ $posts->appends(['q' => request('q')])->links() }}
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#displaying-pagination-results):

> You may append to the query string of pagination links using the `appends` method.